# WMI фильтр в AD. Как исключить из фильтра по типу ОС компьютеры с конкретным именем

Tags: windows, active-directory, wmi, wsus, group-policy

В домене для различных политик работы со WSUS используется два фильтра WMI по типу продукта. Один - для всех серверов и контроллеров домена. Второй - для всех клиентских ОС.
Однако и среди клиентских ОС есть несколько компьютеров, которые хотелось бы исключить из данного фильтра. Пытался сделать это по имени, но не получается подобрать верный синтаксис. Исключенные компьютеры не исключаются и политика продолжает к ним применяться (проверялось командой `gpresult /r`)
Пробовались такие варианты:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem WHERE ProductType = 1 and NOT Name LIKE 'radio-logger'

SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem WHERE ProductType = 1 and NOT Name='radio-logger'

SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem WHERE ProductType = 1 and Name!='radio-logger'
```

Тут где-то ошибка, или вообще сам способ неверен? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы проводите отбор по имени ПК, вы должны обращаться не к `Win32_OperatingSystem`, а к `win32_computerSystem`, а именно:

```
select * from win32_computerSystem where name='radio-logger'
```

В противном случае система, разумеется, ничего не найдёт.
Также учитывайте, что иногда, при критических ошибках конкретного запроса, все последующие запросы в стеке WSUS не проводятся. У вас, правда, критической ошибки быть не должно, просто запрос вернёт 0 совпадений.